# Having trouble compiling and recreating a JAR file using Eclipse

Tags: java

I have a Java JAR file that was developed to run in the browser. It works fine. There doesn't appear to be any sort of build file associated with the source code I've been given and I'm attempting to create a project and/or build script.

The source code references some third party code. What I've done is unzipped the JAR file into a folder that has this structure:

```
\App\src\com
\App\src\META-INF
\App\src\applet
```

The "com" folder contains subfolders which contain the .CLASS files for the third party libraries. "applet" contains the .JAVA source code files (one folder, maybe 15 files).

The code appears to be written in 1.4 syntax (I manually attempted to compile some of the .JAVA files and it complained that some things were deprecated and/or required the older version).

I created a Java Project in Eclipse and pointed it to the \App folder. Then I went into the Properties for the project and went to Libraries and and clicked on "Add Class Folder" and added the \App\src\com folder. Then I went to "Order and Export" and moved this to the top.  I also set the Java Compiler version to 1.4.

I am getting a large number of compiler errors, all of which seem to stem from the fact that it says it can't resolve an import. This import is the set of .CLASS files contained in the "com" subfolders. The namespace matches the directory structure.

This seems like it should be really straightforward, but I've tried various things and don't seem to be making any progress. Based on what I've read I'm sure it has something to do with the pathing but I'm at a loss at this point on how to fix it.

(I'm sure it goes without saying that I'm not a Java dev.)

Any thoughts or ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try to right click on Eclipse's Navigator. Select Import>General>archive file> (Jar file that you want to import).
You should be getting the jar file correctly imported at this point. Do tell me if you face any problems.

Comment: OK, I imported from the JAR into a new folder. Then I copied in the .java files into the directory that currently only has the .CLASS files. How do I get it to compile a new JAR if I make changes to the .java files? I checked the output folder (bin) and it seems like it's set-up to auto-compile, but their isn't any output file/JAR being created.

Comment: You would not need to manually copy the .java files into any directory. The IDE should place it correctly when importing the JAR file. Once you complete your development and testing within Eclipse of the changes that you made to the Source code you extracted from the jar file. You can create a the Jar file by right clicking on folder which contains your jar project, select 'Export>Java>JAR>'. In the next page you would fill in the path that you want the Jar to be placed in etc.

Comment: The original JAR file only included the .CLASS files - no .java files. When I export it I'm getting a few errors like "MyApplet [in MyViewerApplet] is not on its project's build path. Unable to get package fragment root /MyViewerApplet/MyApplet/MySource.java.